# Multiple Users Debugging Pods in a Single Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, namespaces

I would like to deploy a single k8s cluster for development, but i would like that several developers will use it.

By use I mean: **consume cluster services, and deploy their specific modified Pods**

The exception is that I would like that only the developer who deploy it modified Pod, will consume it, and rest of users will still use "default" Pod.

My guess is to use namespace for each developer.

Any ideas how to do that? examples?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: I work in a shared development cluster like this; but each user has their own namespace, and Kubernetes RBAC limits them to only making changes there.  Conversely, we expect each user to deploy the entire stack in their own namespace.  You should be able to straightforwardly configure a service to make _outbound_ calls to `shared-service.default.svc.cluster.local` in another namespace, but receiving _inbound_ calls back from that other service is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like namespaces combined with role-based access control mentioned here might be a good fit for your needs since as per [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) they are to help in those kind of scenarios:

> Namespaces are intended for use in environments with many users spread across multiple teams, or projects.

To get more information on namespaces and how to use them you can check out [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) as well as the [RPAC documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, Yes, I think i can work with it